# How does Paths.get("") determine its search bounds with no parameters?

Tags: java, javafx, path, filepath

I am working on a javafx application which involves music player and I am receiving strange results from Paths.get(""). Here are my examples, so in my IDE it works correctly except that it gets the path of items in both the source folder and the bin. After exporting it into a Runnable Jar File it now results in no files being found after being placed in a folder on my PC, this is despite the fact that I have packaged other files with it in the JAR file. Finally, after running it from a flash drive on another computer it found all the files on my flash drive! Can someone please explain how this process works?

Comment: it does have a parameter, which is an empty string `""`

Comment: Does that affect anything?

Comment: Nope. Just saying hehe

Comment: `Paths.get("")`, whatever it is doing, is getting paths from the file system. So it is never going to find entries in a jar file, since those are not actually files at all. I *think* (and experiments suggest) that relative paths with no other context are resolved against the working directory (i.e. against `System.getProperty("user.dir")`) but I can't find any documentation for that.

Comment: @James_D Ok that makes sense, what function would I use to get files from the jar file (since a jar file is essentially a special ZIP file).

Comment: Again "get files from the jar file" is an oxymoron, since it doesn't contain files, it contains data in a specific hierarchical format. You can get use `getClass().getResource(...)` to get the URL of a resource that is loaded from the same place as the current class (so if the class is loaded from the file system, it returns a `file:` URL, if it is loaded from a jar file, it returns a `jar:` URL, etc.). The resource is relative to the current class, or to the classpath if it begins `/`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) for resource naming.